# Camel 3.10.0 - DEBUG Info

Tags: java, apache-camel, log4j2

Can someone tell me how to turn off DEBUG information in log4j?
this is my log4j2.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel=INFO
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d [%-15.15t] %-5p %-30.30c{1} - %m%n
rootLogger.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = console
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that Camel is using log4j? Or are these "Debug" messages printed directly to `System.out` or even through an entirely different logging framework

Comment: No, actually I'm not sure. I didn't write this code. Do you  know How I can see if these DEBUG message come from different logging framework?

Comment: I solved this problem in an other thread: [Hikari Pool disable Debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68469502/solvedhikari-pool-disable-debug-mode)

Comment: Yes, with this is the right way to solve  this problem.